# Build gcc-cross failed, nothing provides 'gcc-cross'

Tags: yocto, cross-build

I'm building **gcc-cross** with **poky** at the last commit.

and get the error:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'gcc-cross'. Close matches:
  gcc-cross-i586
```

what is defined in **gcc-cross recipe** to prevent **gcc-cross** without target architecture name in tail?